# JAX-RS with embedded server

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, embedded-server

***Clarification:*** this question was about GZIPping an JAX-WS-based REST service, but I've decided to change the topic to make it easier to find

I'm implementing a REST service via JAX-WS `Provider <Source>`, and publishing it with standard `Endpoint` (the reason is that I want to avoid using a servlet container or application server).

Is there a way to make server to gzip response content, if `Accept-Encoding: gzip` is present?

---

### HOW-TO

Samples provided by `nicore` actually works, and it allows you to make JAX-RS-styled server on top of embedded lightweight server without servlet container, but there are few moments to be considered.

If you prefer to manage classes by yourself (and save a time during startup), you may use the following:

#### Example

JAX-RS hello world class:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class RestServer {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getMessage(){
        System.out.println("sayHello()");
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

Main method:

For [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/) Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DefaultResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig(RestServer.class);
    // The following line is to enable GZIP when client accepts it
    resourceConfig.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new GZIPContentEncodingFilter());
    Closeable server = SimpleServerFactory.create("http://0.0.0.0:5555", resourceConfig);
    try {
        System.out.println("Press any key to stop the service...");
        System.in.read();
    } finally {
        server.close();
    }
}
```

For [Grizzly2](http://grizzly.java.net/):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DefaultResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig(RestServer.class);
    // The following line is to enable GZIP when client accepts it
    resourceConfig.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new GZIPContentEncodingFilter());
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://0.0.0.0:5555" , resourceConfig);
    try {
        System.out.println("Press any key to stop the service...");
        System.in.read();
    } finally {
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

#### Resolved dependencies:

Simple:

- [Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/download/) itself
- [jersey-simple-server](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-simple-server/)

Grizzly:

- [grizzly-framework](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/grizzly/grizzly-framework/)
- [grizzly-http](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/grizzly/grizzly-http/)
- [grizzly-http-server](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/glassfish/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http-server/) (different repository!)
- [jersey-grizzly2](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-grizzly2/)

Jersey:

- [jersey-archive](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-archive/)

#### Notice

Make sure the `javax.ws.rs` archive didnt get into your classpath, as it conflicts with Jersey's implementation. The worst thing here is a silent 404 error with no logging - only a small note on `FINER` level is logged.

Comment: Isn't that just up to the container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) to sort out?

Comment: We're not currently using servlet containe, and this REST service is probably the only place where we'll need it. I don't really think it's worth it to examine, set up, and tune a whole servlet container just for gzipping this little guy. So I want to avoid using one, if possible.

Comment: Just for clarity, the examples are for Jersey 1.x and are not accurate for Jersey 2.x.  See the documentation for the latter case: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you really want to do REST with Java I would suggest you to to use a JAX-RS implementation (RESTeasy, Jersey...).

If your main concern is the dependency on a servlet container, you could use the JAX-RS [RuntimeDelegate](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.10/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.html) to register your application as a JAX-RS endpoint.

```
// Using grizzly as the underlaying server
SelectorThread st = RuntimeDelegate.createEndpoint(new MyApplication(), SelectorThread.class);

st.startEndpoint();

// Wait...
st.stopEndpoint();
```

Concerning `GZIP` encoding, each JAX-RS provider has different approaches. Jersey provides [a filter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html) to accomplish the encoding transparently. RESTEasy [provides an annotation for that](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/gzip.html).

**EDIT**

I did some small tests. The following two things will definitely work for you, assuming you are using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Using **Jersey + SimpleServer**:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    java.io.Closeable server = null;

    try {
        // Creates a server and listens on the address below.
        // Scans classpath for JAX-RS resources
        server = SimpleServerFactory.create("http://localhost:5555");
        System.out.println("Press any key to stop the service...");
        System.in.read();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (server != null) {
                server.close();
            }
        } finally {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

with maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-simple-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Or using the **Jersey + Grizzly2**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpServer server = null;

    try {
        server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://localhost:5555");
        System.out.println("Press any key to stop the service...");
        System.in.read();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (server != null) {
                server.stop();
            }
        } finally {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

with maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Honestly speaking I was not able to get the `RuntimeDelegate` sample working, too.
There certainly is a way to start RESTEasy out of the box, too but I cannot recall it at the moment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the JAX-RS (and especially it's `RuntimeDelegate`) is one of the most horrible and bad-designed things I ever saw. I'm struggling with both Jersey and RESTEasy for two hours and still don't get, how to make any of them work without servlet container. Could you please provide a simple example of how to implement that? P.S. And btw - which jar contains `SelectorThread`? Grizzly itself has tons of jars, while Jersey doesn't seems to contain this one.

Comment: Well, I personally like JAX-RS and produced some quite cool things with it. At least it is a better option than developing everything yourself I guess. Concerning the JAR question: I cannot tell the answer because I use maven to sort that out for me. Maybe the Jersey wiki pages help.

Comment: Took time to figure this out, but it work, thank you. I'll accept your answer and edit my question to clarify this for anyone else going this way.

Comment: Probably adding to my necro badge here on SO but what the heck! I'm struggling to get this to work with jersey throwing an exception - "The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes." Also I'm guessing this doesn't need a web.xml which is one of the things I tried. Using jersey-simple-server 1.17.1

Answer (score 0):

gzipping the output is the reponsibility of JAX WS implementation. You should refer to server's (Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, etc) documentation in order to configure your http network listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If using CXF for your JAX-WS implementation (or JAX-RS), you could just add @GZIP annotation onto the service class.