# java jersey rest server with main method?

Tags: java, api, rest, jersey

i need to implement as a part of my application, a http server.
i love the way jersey works and im pretty good at its coding.
is there any way i can implement this kind of server that will be standalone 
and will just run from main method and i can use it as as jersey

```
@GET
@Path("/{screen_name}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

etc..

is there a way to implement it or is there allready some good implementation?

i looked for it for 2 months but i cant find anything

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking for - Jersey will run in many application containers (Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish) and those in turn can be run on many different http servers.

Comment: Jersey is not an HTTP server, its a JAX-RS implementation. It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish, are you trying to embed an application server capable of processing JAX-RS, into a non-web app?

Comment: "are you trying to embed an application server capable of processing JAX-RS, into a non-web app", exactly

Comment: Ok, in that case I will point you to this SO topic discussing [running JAX-RS with an embedded server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277409/jax-rs-with-embedded-server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used  Perceptions answer, worked perfectly with the grizzly,
[JAX-RS with embedded server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277409/jax-rs-with-embedded-server)

thank you very much