# What are the relations between JAX-RS and Servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

Reading the JAX-RS 2.0 specifications, I see that a JAX-RS application could be deployed in JAVA SE, and doesn't need a Servlet.

Nevertheless in a Web Application, the JAX-RS application is pluggable in the web.xml file using :

```
<web-app ...>
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/myresources/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So do we deploy one and only Servlet when creating a JAX-RS application ?

Is it possible to create a JAX-RS application without using the Servlets (for exemple with Netty). Has it been done ?

Comment: This can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277409/jax-rs-with-embedded-server